# QDataStream on external memory?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like serialize QVector into char* array. I do this by the following code:

```
QVector<int> in;
...
QByteArray bytes;
QDataStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << in;
std::copy(bytes.constData(), bytes.constData() + bytes.size(), out);
```

I guarantee that `out` is large enough. Due to the fact that this code is called extremely often I would like to avoid this unnecessary `std::copy` operation and make either `QByteArray` or `QDataStream` work on preallocated user memory pointed by `out`. Is that possible? Any bight ideas?

**UPDATE**: **QByteArray::fromRawData()** doesn't match the needs cause it does not allow to change char* buffer it was created on, in other words, QByteArray performs deep copy on first modification of such created instance.
As they say. *This ensures that the raw data array itself will never be modified by QByteArray.*

**SOLUTION**: The solution proposed by @skyhisi does perfectly match my needs. The complete code is the following.

1. SimpleBuffer.hpp

   ```
   #pragma once
   #include <QtCore/QIODevice>

   class SimpleBuffer : public QIODevice {
     Q_OBJECT
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(SimpleBuffer)

   public:
     SimpleBuffer(char* const begin, const char* const end) :
       _begin(begin),
       _end(end){}

     virtual bool atEnd() const {
       return _end == _begin;
     }

     virtual bool isSequential() const {
       return true;
     }

   protected:
     virtual qint64 readData(char*, qint64) {
       return -1;
     }

     virtual qint64 writeData(const char* const data, const qint64 maxSize) {
       const qint64 space = _end - _begin;
       const qint64 toWrite = qMin(maxSize, space);
       memcpy(_begin, data, size_t(toWrite));
       _begin += toWrite;
       return toWrite;
     }

   private:
     char* _begin;
     const char* const _end;
   };
   ```
2. main.cpp

   ```
   #include "SimpleBuffer.hpp"
   #include <QtCore/QVector>
   #include <QtCore/QDataStream>
   #include <QtCore/QByteArray>

   int main(int, char**) {
     QVector<int> src;
     src << 3 << 7 << 13 << 42 << 100500;
     const size_t dataSize = sizeof(quint32) + src.size() * sizeof(int);
     char* const data = new char[dataSize];

     // prepare stream and write out the src vector
     {
       SimpleBuffer simpleBuffer(data, data + dataSize);
       simpleBuffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
       QDataStream os(&simpleBuffer);
       os << src;
     }

     // read vector with QByteArray
     QVector<int> dst;
     {
       const QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray::fromRawData((char*)data, dataSize);
       QDataStream is(byteArray);
       is >> dst;
     }
     delete [] data;

     // check we've read exactly what we wrote
     Q_ASSERT(src == dst);

     return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to implement a `QIODevice`, you could make a very simple sequential device quite easily. Here's one I've quickly thrown together, I haven't checked it works (feel free to get it working and edit the post).

```
class SimpleBuffer : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        SimpleBuffer(char* begin, char* end):mBegin(begin),mEnd(end){}

        virtual bool atEnd() const {return mEnd == mBegin; }

        virtual bool isSequential() const { return true; }

    protected:
        virtual qint64 readData(char*, qint64) { return -1; }

        virtual qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 maxSize)
        {
            const qint64 space = mEnd - mBegin;
            const qint64 toWrite = qMin(maxSize, space);
            memcpy(mBegin, data, size_t(toWrite));
            mBegin += toWrite;
            return toWrite;
        }

   private:
        char* mBegin;
        char* mEnd;

        Q_DISABLE_COPY(SimpleBuffer)
};
```

Comment: Added your solution to the original message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fromRawData works:

QByteArray QByteArray::fromRawData ( const char * data, int size ) [static]

Using it something like :

```
char* out=new char[enoughbytes]; // preallocate at suitable scope
QVector<int> in; 
QByteArray ba=QByteArray::fromRawData(out,enoughbytes); 
QDataStream stream(&ba,QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
stream << in;
```

Note that QDataStream adds some of it's own data at the start of the data (not much though), so remember to preallocate a bit more for that, as well as for whatever additional data QVector serializes.

Comment: That was my initial idea. But unfortunately `QByteArray` performs deep copy on first modification of such created instance. As they say [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData). _This ensures that the raw data array itself will never be modified by QByteArray._

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [QBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html)?

```
QByteArray myBuffer;
myBuffer.reserve(10000); // no re-allocation

QBuffer buffer(&myBuffer);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QDataStream out(&buffer);
out << QApplication::palette();
```

Comment: Because target buffer (`char* out`) is out of my control and allocated by an external library. The essence of the question was how to wrap this external memory into QDataStream without using intermediate buffers.